# Range error selecting a table column with # character in header

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to lock certain columns in many similarly constructed tables. Date and Time columns lock.

When I try to lock a column with the name "[Phone #1]" as constructed, it gives me a run-time error 1004, Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

Code and screenshot is included below

```
Sub test()
' lockDesiredCellsInWeeklyTables
' This macro was made to lock certain columns in the weekly tables so that some less than technologically adept people wouldn't destroy the cells
Dim shtName As String
Dim tblName As String
Dim tbl As ListObject

shtName = "July"
tblName = "july"
dateName = "[Date]"
timeName = "[Time]"
phone1Name = "[Phone #1]"
phone2Name = "[Phone #2]"
phone3Name = "[Phone #3]"

ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
For i = 1 To 4
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblName & i)
    ' Locks the Date column
    Range(tbl & dateName).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ' Locks the Time column
    Range(tbl & timeName).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ' Locks the Phone #1 column
    Range(tbl & phone1Name).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ' Locks the Phone #2 column
    Range(tbl & phone2Name).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
    ' Locks the Phone #3 column
    Range(tbl & phone3Name).Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True
Next i
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=False _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

Link to the screenshot since I can't post images yet 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhcFf.jpg

Comment: You do not need to `Select` an object (cell in this case) to analyze its properties (like value/name). You should remove all instances of `.Select` and `.Selection` for more reliable code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With structured references, some characters like `#` have special meaning and require the use of a single quotation mark (') as an escape character.  So you'll need to add a single quotation mark (') before each #. ([Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e))

```
phone1Name = "[Phone '#1]"
phone2Name = "[Phone '#2]"
phone3Name = "[Phone '#3]"
```

Also, as urdearboy has already mentioned, there's no need to do any selecting...

```
For i = 1 To 4
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblName & i)
    ' Locks the Date column
    With Range(tbl & dateName)
        .Locked = True
        .FormulaHidden = True
    End With
    ' Locks the Time column
    With Range(tbl & timeName)
        .Locked = True
        .FormulaHidden = True
    End With
    ' Locks the Phone #1 column
    With Range(tbl & phone1Name)
        .Locked = True
        .FormulaHidden = True
    End With
    ' Locks the Phone #2 column
    With Range(tbl & phone2Name)
        .Locked = True
        .FormulaHidden = True
    End With
    ' Locks the Phone #3 column
    With Range(tbl & phone3Name)
        .Locked = True
        .FormulaHidden = True
    End With
Next i
```